# how to know child divs on container div center on scroll event right and left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

trying to do event 'scroll' and when in the callback function the record of position div only record of last position, i want to know if that div in the center target i want

```js
const slide = document.querySelector(".slides")

slide.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  const slide2 = document.querySelector("#slide-2")
  console.log(slide2.offsetLeft)
})
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">5</a>
  <div class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">1</div>
    <div id="slide-2">2</div>
    <div id="slide-3">3</div>
    <div id="slide-4">4</div>
    <div id="slide-5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my goal here I want to know if a user on that div to Right and Left for my slider
so i can make active dots , i am trying to just use native javascript here :)

here is my Codepen example
https://codepen.io/lpllplp222/pen/BaRvwKm

Comment: You need to check the scroll position of the `slides` parent, check if the current position matches with which slide and activates the corresponding dot

Comment: it doesn't reactive change when i call slide.offsetWidth, how i can know the left and right position the correct way??

Comment: Can you use jQuery ?

Comment: i have no idea about jquery :D, but the existing code use pure javascript :D, that is why i ask how to know that scroll event with javascript :) @AbinThaha

Comment: You can use JavaScript to achieve but it will not be an easy solution.Instead you can use jQuery to achieve it easily.

Comment: how to know the event scroll right and left with that slide div? been search but not found anyhow to make it reactive @AbinThaha

Comment: I have added a solution using jQuery. Can you check and comment?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `jQuery` to achieve the same.

`position()` function from the jQuery provides the current position of an element from its top and left, I am using the left value to calculate the current active element and get its index, thereby providing an active class to the corresponding dot.

```js
const slide = document.querySelector(".slides")

$('#slider-dots a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
})

slide.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var scrollLeft = $('#slides-wrapper').scrollLeft();
  var currIndex = -1;
  $('#slider-dots a').removeClass('active');
  for(var i = 0; i<$('#slides-wrapper div').length; i++) {
    if($($('#slides-wrapper div')[i]).position().left >= 0 && currIndex === -1) {
      currIndex = i;
    }
  }
  $($('#slider-dots a')[currIndex]).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  display: flex;

  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;

  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

  /*
  scroll-snap-points-x: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  */
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
#slider-dots a.active {
  color: violet;
  background-color: #000;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.slides::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
.slides > div {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.slides > div:target {
/*     transform: scale(0.8); */
}
.author-info {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.author-info a {
  color: white;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider > a {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}
.slider > a:active {
  top: 1px;
}
.slider > a:focus {
  background: #000;
}

/* Don't need button navigation */
@supports (scroll-snap-type) {
  .slider > a {
    display: none;
  }
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #74abe2, #5563de);
  font-family: "Ropa Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider" id='slider-dots'>
  <a href="#slide-1">1</a>
  <a href="#slide-2">2</a>
  <a href="#slide-3">3</a>
  <a href="#slide-4">4</a>
  <a href="#slide-5">5</a>

  <div id='slides-wrapper' class="slides">
    <div id="slide-1">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="slide-2">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="slide-3">
      3
    </div>
    <div id="slide-4">
      4
    </div>
    <div id="slide-5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i scroll left and right the number is doesn't match on which box going, also on click, when i click 3, it should be active on 3, but your code actived on 2

Comment: For me, I don't see those 2 issues you mentioned.

Comment: dost 5 not active

Comment: it doesn't work on full page when i run code snippet for dots